# How to configure auth0 authentication/authorization without using Auth0 Universal login?

Tags: node.js, authentication, auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-delegated-admin

I need to use Auth0 as authentication service in my node.js app.
The problem is that i don't need their universal login. I have my own and want to use it. I need user to enter his credentials in my form, do a request to node.js app, this node.js app makes a request to auth0 and if credentials are correct, get Authorization token and use it in our system.
In another words, i want to use auth0`s API only.

I tried to use /authorize endpoint, but it redirects me to universall login page.

Also i tried /dbconnections/signup and alvays got "Missing required property: connection", but this property was provided.
And when i POST /oauth/token request i get "Cannot GET /oauth/token"

I tried to use auth0 npm package also, but as i found it doesn't allow to send a credentials and get auth token.

```
var AuthenticationClient = require('auth0').AuthenticationClient;

var auth0 = new AuthenticationClient({
  domain: '{YOUR_ACCOUNT}.auth0.com',
  clientId: '{OPTIONAL_CLIENT_ID}'
});
```

I expect to use auth0 only as api on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [resource owner password grant](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant).